# Batch command to delete all subfolders with specific name having special character

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory as such:

```
D:\DATA\DATA2\Demo&_1\Demo\1\deployment
D:\DATA\DATA2\Demo&_1\Demo\2\deployment
D:\DATA\DATA2\Demo&_1\Demo\3\deployment
```

And I am running the below batch file command to delete all deployment folders present inside Demo folder:

```
cd /d D:\DATA\DATA2\Demo&_1\Demo
FOR /d /r . %%d IN (deployment) DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"
```

The above command is not working(not deleting deployment folder) when I have special character in in folder name (Demo&_1) and when I have do not have special then it is working(deleting deployment folder).

For e.g. if I change name of folder "Demo&_1" to "Demo1" the above batch file will work fine but not work if have special character.

Comment: why not simply do `for /D /R "D:\DATA\DATA2\Demo&_1\Demo"  %%d IN (deployment) DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"` If that does the trick, I will post an answer.

Comment: You were right. Thank you for helping. If you put it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Glad it helped, Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because the paths are not in quotes, but regardless here is a much simpler solution without having to do `cd /d`

```
for /D /R "D:\DATA\DATA2\Demo&_1\Demo" %%d IN (deployment) DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"
```